# In a MacRuby app for distribution, how can you launch an NSTask that invokes a Ruby script with macruby?

Tags: macruby

I have a MacRuby app, and after the app launches, I would like to launch a second process using an NSTask. The second process is a Ruby script bundled with the app. I would like to launch it using the MacRuby macruby interpreter that gets compiled into the app bundle. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the .rb extension from the ruby script, otherwise if you compile the macruby project using macruby_deploy, it will be compiled to rbo file. The script file should have this as its first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Make sure the script will be copied to Resources folder.

Then create and call a NSTask:

```
path = NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource('test', ofType:nil)
task = NSTask.alloc.init
task.setLaunchPath(path)

task.launch
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you tried just calling NSTask?

```
NSTask.launchedTaskWithLaunchPath('script.rb', nil)
```

Then click around in Xcode to make sure that script.rb is in place during execution.